# Displaying multiple lines of text in an Alert Dialog

Tags: android, text, android-alertdialog

I need to display multiple lines of messages, rather than just one paragraph, in an alert dialogue.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle("Place")
.setMessage("Go there" +
        "Go here")
.setNeutralButton("Go Back", null)
.show();
```

Is there a way to start at new lines? Just like hitting enter after a sentence in Microsoft Word?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No guarantees on this, but usually to do multiple lines you do something like:

```
.setMessage("Go there\nGo here");
```

The "\n" is an escape character that means "New Line" I don't know about your specific case, but you can use it in just about everything AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

Use the "\n" tag in your strings:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Place")
    .setMessage("Go there" + "\n" +
            "Go here")
    .setNeutralButton("Go Back", null)
    .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a carriage return or line feed character? These are characters 10 and 13 respectively (special characters \n and \r, or \u000a and \u000d)

Comment: Elaborating, a newline in word in a typical environment is a CR/LF or character 13 followed by character 10 (\r\n).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to avoid break line and use a custom view component.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
TextView tw =new TextView(this);
        tw.setMaxLines(10);
        tw.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        tw.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        tw.setSingleLine(false);
        tw.setText("ver long messagge \n with break line \n");
        builder.setView(tw);
```

With this solution you can break the line if you want using `\n`, but if you don't, the text will be wrapped on multiple lines (since I set `tw.setSingleLine(false);`).