# AlertDialog not displaying in two lines

Tags: android, dialog

I have solved my problem with the `alertDialog.dismiss();` issue but now I have one with my two line dialog. See when the dialog pops up it only displays this `alertDialog.setMessage("1st line" + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "2nd line");` and I also need it to display this one as well `alertDialog.setMessage("1st line that doesn't display" + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "2nd line that doesn't display");` I really do not understand why this is happening so can anybody help me with this.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alertDialog.setTitle("ApplicationTitle");
alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
alertDialog.setMessage("1st line that doesn't display" + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "2nd line that doesn't display");                
alertDialog.setMessage("1st line" + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "2nd line"); 
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }
 });

alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: You can avoid using line separators using a custom TextView see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511261/displaying-multiple-lines-of-text-in-an-alert-dialogue/37993663#37993663

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the whole text in one call to method `setMessage`:

```
alertDialog.setMessage("1st line that doesn't display"
            + System.getProperty("line.separator")
            + "2nd line that doesn't display"
            + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "1st line"
            + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "2nd line");
```

If you use the method twice or more, only the text set in the last call will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you very much the whole message is displaying but the two line style dialog is still not displaying... any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
     StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
     build.append("1st line")
     .append("\n")
     .append("2nd line")
     .append("\n")
     .append("3rd line");

final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alertDialog.setTitle("ApplicationTitle");

alertDialog.setMessage(build.toString());     


alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
 });
alertDialog.show();
```